# How to create USER CONTROL like panel

Tags: asp.net

I want create a user control (Div) like panel to be used in all my web pages. For example, The UserControl can have two DIVs or TRs with a background design. If it's added to a Page, the UserControl has to allow controls to be added into it, i.e. Divs, Labels, and TextBoxes. The height of the div should be AUTO. Please help me.

Comment: What is an 's'? Can you please explain further.

Answer (score 3):

Add the following property to your UserControl:

```
[PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)]
[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
[TemplateInstance(TemplateInstance.Single)]
public ITemplate Content
{
    get
    {
        return _content;
    }
    set
    {
        _content = value;
    }
}
private ITemplate _content;
```

Then handle the the Content in the CreateChildControls method:

```
protected override void CreateChildControls()
{
    if (this.Content != null)
    {
        this.Content.InstantiateIn(this);
    }
    base.CreateChildControls();
}
```

In markup you can now add anything you want into the Content tags of the Control:

```
<ctl:YourControl runat="server" ID="Foo" style="background-color:#666">
   <Content>
      <asp:Label ... />
      <asp:TextBox... />
   </Content>
</ct1:YourControl>
```

Comment: I want to add <DIV1> content to add</DIV1> <DIV2> content to add</DIV2>     or    <DIV1> FIXED <DIV2> Content</DIV2>

Comment: No idea what you're on about to be honest. I suggest you try and be more concise.

Answer (score 0):

write the control panel code on a different page.

on the pages check if its needed and include the control panel. if there are other elements on the page which will need special controls.

you can do a if() and add the controls there.

Comment: I want to place controls in <DIV> which has background color